# Which driver need to install in my android device for running my app?

Tags: android, eclipse, usb, adb

I bought intex mobile for testing my android application in real device. However this device is not present in the list of devices provided by android in OEM USB Driver list. I checked intex official site but not sure exactly which driver need to install. Can you please tell me exactly which driver i need to install so that i can run my application from eclipse in my "intex cloud y11" device. For website URL [click here intex website](http://www.intexmobile.in/download_drivers.asp)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using windows, Download the latest Universal usb driver or whatever you want.
There is a file "android_winusb.inf" inside that driver pack. 
Open it with a text editor like notepad. If you are using windows 64-bit, search for "[Google.NTamd64]" inside that file. 
copy one of the devices listed below that. something like this:

```
;
;Google NexusOne
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0D02&MI_01
;
```

Replace those VIDs and PIDs with your device's.
You can find it in Device Manager. Right click on your device and click on Properties.
then under Details tab you can find all the information you need. select "Hardware Ids" in Property. or "Bus relations" shows everything you need.

after replacing those values, you can change the name "Google NexusOne" to whatever you want.

then save the file and driver for your device is ready.

Comment: Thank you very much MDP. It worked. Thanks again you saved my lot of time. Please up this ans.