# Unable to debug with ADB on Samsung Galaxy S3 (target not recognized)

Tags: android, adb, adt, samsung-mobile

My Samsung galaxy S3 phone doesn't seem to be recognized as a valid target to debug using ADB. USB debugging is enabled in the phone settings and I am able to run my app if I manually install the .apk.
[image: Unknown target]

There seems to be an old ASUS driver in the way that I cannot get rid of (I used to debug on an ASUS TF101 transformer tablet) even though I uninstalled the driver and tried to delete anything related to it.
[image: Device Manager ASUS]

I have already tried to update the driver using the Google USB Drivers and the Drivers provided by Samsung.

I have also tried with my colleague's Nexus 5 with similar result.
I have tried Uninstalling the ADT/ADB and all drivers and re-install from scratch without success

Any Idea what I can do short of formatting my computer in order to be able to debug on my device.

Comment: Do you have a custom rom on your s3? Have you installed the Google Drivers from the latest SDK Manager?

Comment: @Emanuel There is non custom rom in the s3. I think I have installed the latest google drivers (v9) from the latest SDK since I updated everything yesterday.

Comment: uninstall the driver with checkbox "Delete the driver software..." checked. then manually create a driver for yourself: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24220034/2855059)

Comment: @M D P - I was finally able to debug on my phone. I was an authorization issue. It seems that tere might be a per-phone limit of authorization.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was that the "allow usb debugging" dialog wasn't being displayed as per this post: [Can't connect Nexus 4 to adb: unauthorized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18011685/cant-connect-nexus-4-to-adb-unauthorized)

By clearing the previous authorization, I got the dialog to pop and could authorize the debugging.

I had already authorized debugging on 2 other computers (a while ago). I wonder if there might be a limit to the ammount of authorizations that 1 phone can issue.

For more details on the feature, you can read this article: [Secure USB debugging in Android 4.2.2](http://nelenkov.blogspot.ca/2013/02/secure-usb-debugging-in-android-422.html)