# Android Studio adb - USB Device Not Found - Verizon Resolution

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, htc-android

How do I get Android Studio adb to recognize my usb device (HTC Droid DNA) I keep getting the USB device not found message in the abd log. Windows also will not install my drivers and my HTC sync manager is updated?

Android Studio 0.5.2
Device: Droid DNA
OS: Windows 8.1
JRE. 1.7.0_25

Comment: I had a similar error. All I did was unplug and replug back in.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this issue for awhile that my Droid DNA wouldn't be recognized by Android Studio. Initially I thought it was related to drivers - which it was and the HTC Manager. I got that upgraded successfully. Still nothing. Then windows wasn't recognizing the actual device in the device manager and would not perform the upgrade.

Then realized that the usb port I was using was not compatible with the usb cord I was using to perform an upgrade for USB Mass Storage. I moved usb ports and re-ran the update for windows drivers successfully. Still no adb detection. Did more digging and found a great step by step fix. The latest software version to my DNA phone completely removed and hid the developer options in the settings. Verizon's help resources had the fix. My phone was not set to perform usb debugging (has nothing to do with the internet pass through settings which I thought was the developer settings replacement for an hour or more).

In short do this (these items look clickable and usually do nothing but do in this instance) in the Settings - About - Software Information - More - Click the build number 7 times. You will start getting a Toast message about on your way to being a developer. Once done go back to main settings an Developer Options is now visible and accessible.

Hope this helps and saves others the 4 hours I spent on this. Apps are now installing for debugging on my device.

The fix is here at verizons site: http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/devices/knowledge_base.html/70154

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After setting up debugging on the phone, I still couldn't connect.
I went to the HTC website and downloaded and instelled the "HTC Sync Manager". My phone was now connected to the PC properly and Android Studio recognized my phone and I was able to debug the app.

http://www.htc.com/us/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your device's usb driver is not installed and you can't find it anywhere. 
you should create a driver manually. first download an Android USB Driver for windows 8.1.
then open the inf file and change it. I described here: [Which driver need to install in my android device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24220034/2855059)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when trying to debug using my Motorola X919, "USB device not found".

What i did first was to enable Developer Mode and USB Debugging option on my phone. When i connected my device to the laptop, the driver installation process started automatically and then it failed.

Then, I downloaded Motorola Device Manager (there must be an equivalent for other brands) and installed it with the phone plugged, and it installed the required drivers successfully, so now Android ADB recognize my phone and i am able to debug my app using a physical device.